# ruby filename path to string error

Tags: ruby, filepath

This is my code:

```
file = File.open('result.txt', 'w+').read

path = Dir[ENV['HOME'] + '/Desktop/Test/*.txt']

file.puts "this is a #{path} test: "
```

It comes up with an error:

```
C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/Comparison/test.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': private method `puts' called for "":String (NoMethodError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

my intended result is:

```
this is a C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/new_1.txt test:
```

i've tried this:

```
puts "this is a #{path[0]} test: "
```

which achieves what i want but as soon as i do `file.puts` it comes up with the same error again.

Comment: are you trying to append to the file or print to the screen?

Comment: I'm trying to put the results in the file

Answer (score 0):

When you do `file.puts` here, you're sending a method `#puts` to a string object that's now stored in the variable `file`. This is because `File#read` method returns a string. So, on the first line, `file` takes the contents of the `result.txt` and then stores it in the variable `file. Then you're calling`puts`on that string. And`String#puts` is a private method, so you can't use it the way you used it in the code above.

If your intention is to write the result `this is a C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/new_1.txt test:`, then you need to use the `File.open` method this way:

```
File.open('result.txt', 'w+') do |file|
  path = Dir[ENV['HOME'] + '/Desktop/Test/*.txt']
  file.puts "this is a #{path} test: "
  # whatever else needs to be written goes here
end
```

Or, if you prefer the imperative style instead of the block style:

```
file = File.new('result.txt', 'w+')
# If you prefer `open`, that works too!
# file = File.open('result.txt', 'w+')
path = Dir[ENV['HOME'] + '/Desktop/Test/*.txt']
file.puts "this is a #{path} test: "

# ensure this is closed, or you'll have memory issues if you do this often
file.close
```

Comment: Thanks! this now prints to the results file but it comes up as `this is a ["C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/new_1.txt"] test: ` how do i lose the square brackets and quotation marks?

Comment: When you mention `Test/*.txt`, it means that it's an array, so this output is correct. However, if you want to join the array elements, you can do something like: `"this is a #{path.join(', ')} test: "`  on the 3rd line

Comment: i don't want to join them i just want to output to look like `this is a C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/new_1.txt test:` with the name changing according to whatever filename it is